# Squid password change not working inside docker container

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have changed username and password for squid proxy, but some how its not taking any effect and only accepts old credentials.
Also the password file /etc/squid/passwords have updated credentials in it.
I have also tried restarting the squid but nothing works.

I am expecting to login to proxy with new credentials